# Laravel/Eloquent - Modeling a HasOne relationship via a BelongsToMany relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-nova

Say I have four tables:

- users
- groups
- activities
- group_activities

Where a group can have any number of `activities` and an activity can belong to any number of `groups` through their intermediate table `group_activities`, and a user belongs to one group via `users.group_id`. I want to correctly model a relationship between `users` and `activities` so that a user can have any *one* activity, but only if the group that user belongs to has a relation to that activity.

HasOneThrough doesn't seem to work here, since the group the user is related through has multiple activities. HasManyThrough doesn't work since the user can only have one.

I want to properly model this relationship so that it can be picked up for selection automatically via a Nova relationship field, but I'm struggling to figure out exactly how I would do so. My first thought is a HasOneThrough relation with some set of subqueries, but I can't quite piece together where to start.

How would I do this, or conversely, is it possible via Eloquent's automatic relationship system at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To ensure we are on the same idea of your relationships:**

The relationship between Groups and Activities is a Many To Many relationship ([Many To Many - Larvel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)).

The `group_activities` table is the pivot table.

The relationship between users and groups is a One To Many relationship [One To Many - Larvel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) and the inverse of it [One To Many (Inverse) - Larvel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse).

**To actually answer your question:**

If you want to use a shortcut from users to their activities, the Has Many Through is the correct way. If a group can have arbitrary many activities, and a user belongs to one group, the user will be associated to these arbitrary many activities through the group -hence Has Many Through. Note that this is not really a separate relationship though, it's just a convient shortcut.

If you wan't to associate a user with a single Activity directly, you need to to this via a separate One to Many relationship between Users and Activities.

I'm not entirely sure if I interpret your question correctly, so the following is just an assumption, but do you want to ensure a user can only be associated to an activity thats also associated with the user group? So to restrict possible activites by group? If that is the case, you'd simply need to check if the selected activity is in the activities associated with the users group:

With your relationships set up like this:

```php
class User {

    public function activity(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Activity');
    }

    public function possibleActivities(){
         return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Activity','App\Group');
    }
}
```

you can check and associate activities like this:

```php
if( $user->possibleActivities()->contains( $activity ) ){
    $user->activity()->associate($activity);
}
```

Comment: This should work for the most part. It wont fly with Nova's field magic, but it's enough that I can make psuedofields and handle the logic in an observer.

Comment: For anyone who wants to use this for Laravel Nova, as I did - the approach I took was to generate a Select dropdown from `$user->possibleActivities()->pluck('label', 'activities.id')` with the `onlyOnForms()` method - then generate a custom field with `hideWhenUpdating()` and `hideWhenCreating()` linking the activity and its label with a `getAttribute` method on the User, that uses the `$user->activity` accessor.